# Windows batch file return code isn't set if there's a following line

Tags: batch-file

The following Windows batch file called "foo.bat" echos "quitting" and sets the return code to 1 as I expect:

```
if "1"=="1" (
  if "1"=="1" (
    echo quitting
    exit /B 1
  )
)
```

But, to my surprise, the return code of this batch file is 0:

```
if "1"=="1" (
  if "1"=="1" (
    echo quitting
    exit /B 1
  )

  echo anything
)
```

I determine the batch file's return code like so in the Windows command prompt:

```
> cmd.exe /c foo.bat
quitting
> echo %ERRORLEVEL%
0
```

I've verified that ERRORLEVEL is not already set in my environment, running `set ERRORLEVEL` prints "Environment variable ERRORLEVEL not defined" as expected.

Everything else about the second file works as expected. It *does* echo "quitting" and *does not* echo "anything". It appears that adding the `echo anything` line to the script means that the line `exit /B 1` still exits but does not set the return code.

This is Windows 7 in EC2. `ver` reports "Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]".

Is there a way to ensure `exit /B 1` really sets the return code, even in complex if statements?

Comment: I cannot reproduce that, neither on Windows 7 nor on Windows 10. Have you tested exactly the code you posted?

Comment: How are you testing the return code? Just `echo %errorlevel%`? You didn't set the errorlevel variable manually, did you?

Comment: I also cannot reproduce your result. Please show the batch script that calls "foo.bat" and tests the returned ERRORLEVEL. If the test was run from the command line, then show the exact sequence of commands that demonstrate the errant result. Also verify that you don't have a user defined ERRORLEVEL environment variable defined that overrides the dynamic value (use `set errorlevel` - you should get `Environment variable errorlevel not defined` message)

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my answer. I've shown the commands I use to test the returned ERRORLEVEL, and I've checked that ERRORLEVEL is not user-defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I change the file extension from ".bat" to ".cmd", then it behaves as expected.

Comment: no it does not;
`
    G:\>cmd /c a.cmd
    
    G:\>if "1" == "1" (
    if "1" == "1" (
    echo quitting
     exit /B 1
    )
     echo anything
    )
    quitting
    
    G:\>echo %errorlevel%
    0
`

Answer (score 0):

What is your test environment? 
Are you shure therE are no other side effects involved?

This batch got the expected results in Win7Ult and Win10pro

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
ver > nul
Call :First 
Echo called First  ErrorLevel = %Errorlevel%
ver > nul
Call :Second
Echo called Second ErrorLevel = %Errorlevel%

Pause
Goto:Eof

:First
if "1"=="1" (
  if "1"=="1" (
    echo quitting
    exit /B 1
  )
)
Goto :EoF

:Second
if "1"=="1" (
  if "1"=="1" (
    echo quitting
    exit /B 1
  )

  echo anything
)
```

---

```
quitting
called First  ErrorLevel = 1
quitting
called Second ErrorLevel = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble. I solved it with something like this:

```
if "1"=="1" (
    if "1"=="1" (
        echo quitting
        goto Exit1
    )
    echo anything
)
goto :Eof

:Exit1
exit /b 1
```

Another "known" defect is this:

```
rem t.bat
copy non-existing somewhere
rem

C:\> cmd /c t.bat
The system cannot find the file specified.
C:\> echo %errorlevel%
0
```

Explicit returning of errorlevel at end of batch file does not work when run with cmd /c if there is a comment after (or echo or something that is supposed to not normally change the errorlevel). So need to use this instead:

```
rem t.bat
copy non-existing somewhere
exit /b %errorlevel%
rem

C:\> cmd /c t.bat
The system cannot find the file specified.
C:\> echo %errorlevel%
1
```